# Spring Boot App not run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run Spring boot application but I am facing a  problem. Help me please. Why do I have this error?

pom.xml

```
    <groupId>com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter</groupId>
    <artifactId>laughtercounter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>laughtercounter</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

`AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Application

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8888

spring.main.banner-mode=off

#database config
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/laughterDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

#rabbit config
rabbit.host=localhost
rabbit.port=5672
rabbit.username=guest
rabbit.password=guest


#60 sec
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
# max 5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ClientController {

    final private ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    public ClientController(ClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestBody List<Client> client,
                       BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Not correct request data");
        }

        clientService.create(client);
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private int seat;
    private String gender;
    private int cameraId;
    private int height;
    private int topY;
    private int width;
    private int leftX;
    private long smile;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> {

}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ClientServiceImpl(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void create(List<Client> client) {
        client.forEach(x -> clientRepository.save(x));
    }
}
```

Error output

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:37019', transport: 'socket'
2017-03-02 17:47:09.286  INFO 8561 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@294e5088: startup date [Thu Mar 02 17:47:09 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-02 17:47:10.066  INFO 8561 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-02 17:47:10.188  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$332fe413] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:11.174  INFO 8561 --- [           main] c.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-02 17:47:11.212  INFO 8561 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3aefae67: startup date [Thu Mar 02 17:47:11 EET 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@294e5088
2017-03-02 17:47:14.472  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2017-03-02 17:47:14.546  WARN 8561 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-03-02 17:47:14.947  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ffa7c2d3-1b2b-3c4f-b2a5-e20a48541c23
2017-03-02 17:47:15.024  INFO 8561 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-02 17:47:15.293  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd819f44] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.390  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd9793b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.462  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1715e116] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.574  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$60281734] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.649  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$549bdbd8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.740  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.cache-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.764  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.775  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6374eb9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.833  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManager' of type [class org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:15.835  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:16.048  INFO 8561 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$332fe413] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-02 17:47:17.019  INFO 8561 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2017-03-02 17:47:17.044  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-02 17:47:17.047  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2017-03-02 17:47:17.303  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-02 17:47:17.304  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6092 ms
2017-03-02 17:47:17.878  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-02 17:47:17.887  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 17:47:17.888  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 17:47:17.889  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 17:47:17.890  INFO 8561 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-02 17:47:18.914  INFO 8561 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-02 17:47:18.961  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-03-02 17:47:19.407  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-03-02 17:47:19.413  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-03-02 17:47:19.417  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-03-02 17:47:19.646  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-03-02 17:47:20.841  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
2017-03-02 17:47:21.174  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-03-02 17:47:21.179  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3b4f1eb
2017-03-02 17:47:21.569  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-03-02 17:47:21.572  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-03-02 17:47:21.633  INFO 8561 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-02 17:47:21.731  WARN 8561 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientController' defined in file [/home/spanky/IdeaProjects/laughter-counter-server/target/classes/com/bwebmedia/laughtercounter/controller/ClientController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/spanky/IdeaProjects/laughter-counter-server/target/classes/com/bwebmedia/laughtercounter/service/impl/ClientServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.repository.ClientRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-03-02 17:47:21.732  INFO 8561 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-02 17:47:21.732  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-03-02 17:47:21.733  INFO 8561 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-03-02 17:47:21.745  INFO 8561 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-02 17:47:21.797  INFO 8561 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-02 17:47:22.103 ERROR 8561 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.service.impl.ClientServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.repository.ClientRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.repository.ClientRepository' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:37019', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Error in not @Autowired repository. Not find models and other parts. I'm use Linux(Ubuntu dist). Sometimes write error with context. Why I am facing this error?

Comment: The error message says "Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter.repository.ClientRepository' in your configuration." - Your ``ClientRepository`` is only an interface, might that be the issue?

Comment: Repository might be interface, not?

Comment: What packages are you classes in?

Comment: com.bwebmedia.laughtercounter

Answer (score 0):

Do not exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in your `AppConfig` class.

Comment: I'm remove but nothing happen